# Height of convex, non-rectangular quad at position x,y?

Tags: math, game-physics

If I have a convex, non-rectangular quad which is facing "up" (the normal has a positive Z value) how can I find the z coordinate at a given x,y location?

I've already determined that the x,y coordinate is within the quad.

We can assume the quad points are all co-planar if that makes things easier.

The more code-like an answer the more helpful it will be, as mathematical symbols don't really work in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane passing through a point p=(px,py,pz) which has normal vector n=(nx,ny,nz) is composed by points (x,y,z) which satisfy the equation:

```
nx * (px-x) + ny * (py-y) + nz * (pz-z) = 0.
```

If you know that nz != 0 you can compute z:

```
z = pz + (nx * (px - x) + ny * (py -y))/nz
```

Comment: Thank you. For px,py,pz I can substitute in any one of the 4 quad points?

Comment: Yes. You should check that all four points satisfy the equation. If this is not the case maybe the quad is not planar, or the normal vector is not really normal.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry one more question: why must pz not be 0?

Comment: Maybe you meant nz must not be 0? Anyway, thank you so much, it's working perfectly for me!